# Getting random entries based off of category

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table called Articles. The structure of this table is as follows: id (unique), category (the category of the article, i.e entertainment), title (the title of the article), image (the image URL of the article), link (the URL of the article), Counter (the number of views the article has), dateStamp (the date the article was published).

Let's say I want to print off 6 random entertainment articles. The easy, but less efficient way of going about this is doing something like

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE category = 'entertainment' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6);
```

Instead, how do I go about it more efficiently? I know there are multiple websites explaining alternatives to ORDER BY RAND(), but I just am not understanding these alternatives. I want to understand based off my structure. I've tried multiple things from shuffling the associative array to creating a random generator, but all ended up in frustration because I couldn't manage to get it to work right. How can I get 6 random entertainment articles printed off without using ORDER BY RAND()?

Comment: is your table big (let's say more than 1000 entries) ? If not, you can SELECT all data, and use PHP to get a random line inside the result...

Comment: @Random It's not big right now, but it will get big in the future, so I want a solution for it now, so I don't have to go back and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal way to do it, one of the efficient options is to select random **subset** of data by given (optional) criteria, `category` in your case. Note the added index onto this column.

```
SELECT
    r1.*
FROM
    articles AS r1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles)) AS id) AS r2
WHERE
    r1.id >= r2.id
    AND r1.category = 'entertainment'
LIMIT 6;
```

Here the details with example data (3.2m rows) and execution plan:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|  3200000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> SELECT
    r1.*
FROM
    articles AS r1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles)) AS id) AS r2
WHERE
    r1.id >= r2.id
    AND r1.category = 'entertainment'
LIMIT 6;
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| id      | topic       | message                                                   | category      |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| 3153910 | JAX68VVH3FZ | Sed eu eros. Nam consequat dolor                          | entertainment |
| 3153911 | NIY23HWV0VM | tortor. Nunc commodo auctor velit. Aliquam nisl. Nulla eu | entertainment |
| 3153912 | LKQ42FRB7LA | mus. Proin vel nisl. Quisque                              | entertainment |
| 3153913 | PFL39VHI9RM | gravida                                                   | entertainment |
| 3153914 | FGV59TUN9TQ | elit, pellentesque a, facilisis non, bibendum sed,        | entertainment |
| 3153915 | OWH73EBZ1GW | ligula. Nullam enim. Sed nulla ante, iaculis              | entertainment |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.473 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> explain extended 
SELECT
    r1.*
FROM
    articles AS r1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM articles)) AS id) AS r2
WHERE
    r1.id >= r2.id
    AND r1.category = 'entertainment'
LIMIT 6;
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys   | key     | key_len | ref   | rows    | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | system | NULL            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  |       1 |      100 | NULL                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | r1         | ref    | PRIMARY,cat_IDX | cat_IDX | 768     | const | 1560229 |      100 | Using index condition        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | NULL       | NULL   | NULL            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | NULL    | NULL     | No tables used               |
|  3 | SUBQUERY    | NULL       | NULL   | NULL            | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  | NULL    | NULL     | Select tables optimized away |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------+---------+---------+-------+---------+----------+------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The difference in the performance is saginificant (more than 10 times) than usual case over same amount of data:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category = 'entertainment' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6;
+---------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| id      | topic       | message                                                                   | category      |
+---------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
| 2374491 | PZC33VGM0ML | Duis cursus, diam at pretium aliquet, metus urna convallis erat,          | entertainment |
|  382306 | RFN88EPE4MI | malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam fringilla cursus purus. Nullam | entertainment |
| 1867986 | KWX30ULB1FR | pede.                                                                     | entertainment |
| 1528863 | ADX52RRJ3MQ | lacus. Mauris non                                                         | entertainment |
| 2188208 | AOD82PXQ6FS | diam luctus lobortis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora              | entertainment |
|  878426 | ABV08HTB2PG | eu eros. Nam consequat dolor vitae dolor. Donec fringilla. Donec          | entertainment |
+---------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
6 rows in set (5.726 sec)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have one question, what is r1 when you say SELECT r1.* ?

Comment: Also, I have 7 entertainment entries. I want 6 random entertainment articles to be displayed exactly, this query is sometimes displaying 4, 5, etc. A number 1-6. What would I do if I wanted 6 articles to be displayed exactly?